# Regex: Put a comma between words in a particular meta-tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this meta tag

`<meta name="keywords" content="Doing well is a great thing"/>`

must become:

`<meta name="keywords" content="doing, well, is, a, great, thing"/>`

I try something like this, does not working:

SEARCH: `(<([^<meta name="keywords" content=>]+)>(.*?))`

Replace by: `/1/2,`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<meta name="keywords" content="|\G)\w+\K\h+`
- Replace with: `,` # comma & space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                                     # non capture group
    <meta name="keywords" content="     # literally
  |                                   # OR
    \G                                  # restart from last match position
)                                       # end group
\w+                                     # 1 or more word character
\K                                      # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+                                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @JustMe: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: I just discover a bug. If I had signs like `-` or `|` regex will skip the replace. Please consider this example: `<meta name="keywords" content="enough place to shelter bebe-oana missing | Love Is everywhere"/>` If you can solve also this, please update your solution or make another one.

Comment: @JustMe: What should be the result? Have a try when replacing `\w+` with `\S+`

Comment: thanks, consider please, the second solution of your answer !